# How to install a node.js package using npm

Tags: node.js, gulp

I need help trying to install a node.js package from Github using the npm command prompt. It's an adaptive grid Jquery plugin called Masonjs: https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason.

It's my first time to use node.js, hence the difficulty understanding the setup instructions. I've CD'd to the project folder and run the 'install npm' and 'install bower' steps successfully, but I don't understand how to complete the remaining steps: running and building Gulp (is building necessary?).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please node that Masonjs is a client side jquery-plugin and has nothing to do with node.js. And the usage of bower is optional. So I think the instructions provided on https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use masonjs library in your project, you don't need to run gulp commands for running and building. Just cd into your project directory where you have initialized npm/bower and run `npm install masonjs` / `bower install masonjs`.

The next step would be to add the `mason.js` file in your index page. Now there would be different folder structure in which this `mason.js` file is present.

In case of npm module the path would be `{your-project-directory}/node_modules/masonjs/lib`

And in case of bower components the path would be `{your-project-directory}/bower_components/MasonJS/dist`

Now just use this library and it will work perfectly.